# Most optimal file format to combine multipart data from S3 in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

S3 has this feature, called multi-part upload. It allows to maintain long lasting session for single S3 object creation out of multiple parts.

We are looking for a binary file format which allows adding parts of the file independently from each other from different processes (running on different nodes or same node), to be reassembled by S3 multi-part upload feature.

In our case Multipart upload leads to large number of S3 buckets, the Spark job is taking too long to execute. Is there a way to optimize reading those files from Spark?

Comment: watching for answers